# Using MicroSD cards with Metro Apps on the Surface RT

Tags: libraries, micro-sd-card, windows-rt, windows-store-app

You can add a MicroSD card to the Surface RT (required since in the 32 GB version the OS itself takes up 12 GB or so), but inexplicably you cannot add your data/media stored on the card to a Library. This makes it impossible to access the data from most Metro apps (especially the default ones from Microsoft) that access the Library locations by default:

[image: 1]

Great job there, Microsoft! [image: 2] So, how do we solve this vexing issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Ideally you should organise your data on the card, such as for example having dedicated folders for Music, Videos etc.
2. Create a folder named `C:\SD` (or whatever you prefer)
3. Open `Disk Management` from the <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> menu (also accessible by right-clicking at the bottom left corner of the screen)
4. Right-click the card's data partition and select `Change Drive Letter and Paths`
5. Click `Add`, then `Browse` in the `Add Drive Letter or Path` window that pops up:
6. Select the folder you created in step #2 above
7. You will see the folder listed as an alternative path to access the card's contents:

   [image: 1]

   You can verify by opening Windows Explorer and navigating to the folder. It will display the exact same files as are on your card.
8. Now you can go to the Music or Videos etc. Libraries and add `C:\SD\Music` or `C:\SD\Videos` etc. as the case may be to them
9. The Library locations should now be visible in the Music, Video and other apps as expected, although the data is still stored only on the card

<sup>Hat tip: Paul Thurrott, although he didn't come up with the junction point workaround</sup>