# Adding a Micro SD card to libraries on Windows RT

Tags: libraries, windows-rt, micro-sd-card

There was an article on this site describing how to add an SD card to the libraries so contents are visible in Music and other apps on Windows RT.

I tried it and it worked really well on my Asus Vivo Tab RT. I say "worked" because my tab developed a problem with the screen and had to be repaired. In the process they blanked my hard drive and I had to set everything up again.

When I tried to do this a second time I got an error of 'invalid parameter' when I tried to change the drive path.

I'm really hoping you have a solution to this as it so drastically affects how useful my tablet is.

Comment: Hi James! Can you link us to the post you mention in the first paragraph?

Comment: @slhck http://winsupersite.com/article/windows8/surface-tip-microsd-content-libraries-metro-apps-144658

Comment: http://superuser.com/questions/497353/using-microsd-cards-with-metro-apps-on-the-surface-rt/546690#546690

Comment: In Step #5, did you click **Add** or **Change**?